# Read and write JSON and maintain the formatting in Ruby

Tags: ruby, json

I have a nicely structured (human made) JSON file that I would like to programatically add and update values.

The issue is that the current structure of the JSON file is very easy to read for me and my colleagues, and we would like it to stay in the same (or very similar) indentation, line spacing and key order, etc.

Is there a way to do this with Ruby?

Comment: What does managing JSON have to do with Rails?

Comment: @WaleedKhan Rails has http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/JSON.html so it might be useful to the solution, or not. It doesn't really matter.

Comment: That would be the [ActiveSupport gem](https://rubygems.org/gems/activesupport).

Comment: @WaleedKhan OK, you win. Removing any mention of Rails.

Answer (score 1):

Ruby's JSON supports [`pretty_generate`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/json/rdoc/JSON.html#method-i-pretty_generate), which is a "pretty" generator, but in no way will it attempt to remember how you've structured a particular JSON data file, nor should it.

```
foo = {'a' => 1, 'b' => %w[2 3]}
puts JSON.generate(foo)
{"a":1,"b":["2","3"]}
puts JSON.pretty_generate(foo)
{
  "a": 1,
  "b": [
    "2",
    "3"
  ]
}
```

JSON is a data serialization format, and, along with YAML and XML, it's designed to move data accurately. Doing that while maintaining an arbitrary line spacing, or leading white-space adds no value to a serializer.

Remember, adding "pretty" to the output increases the size of the data being moved, without improving the quality:

```
puts JSON.generate(foo).size
21

puts JSON.pretty_generate(foo).size
43
```

Making just that little hash "pretty" doubled the size, which, over time, reduces throughput to browsers or across networks between servers. I'd recommend only bothering with the "pretty" output when initially debugging your code, then abandoning it once you're happy with the data movement, in favor of speed and efficiency. The data will be the same.

If you're worried about being able to modify some of the data, write a simple reader and/or JSON generator that works from a standard Ruby data object, then let JSON serialize it, and write the output to a file.